# firestoreConnect Error: Collection is required to build query name

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux-firebase

I'm trying to configure react-redux-firebase to work with redux-firestore. I followed the example setup [from the official Docs](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/firestore.html) and everything seems to work until i wire up a component with firestorConnect from react-redux-firebase. As soon as the connected Component mounts I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Collection is required to build query name

This is how I am attempting to connect my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase';

export class TestComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>test</div>;
  }
}

export default compose(
  firestoreConnect(['test']),
  connect(state => ({
    test: state.firestore.ordered.test
  }))
)(TestComponent);
```

**Update**

The Problem could be resolved by specifying the collections in the following way:

`firestoreConnect([{ collecion: 'test' }])`

That's strange because the [official Docs](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/firestore.html#firestoreConnect), state that the follwoing should also work.

```
import { compose } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase'

export default compose(
 firestoreConnect(['todos']), // or { collection: 'todos' }
 connect((state, props) => ({
   todos: state.firestore.ordered.todos
 }))
)(SomeComponent)
```

I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error and in my case i was missing the `collection` key in `firestoreConnect`.

**Wrong**:

```
export default compose(
  firestoreConnect([
    { projects: 'projects' }
  ]),
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
)(Header);
```

**Right**:

```
export default compose(
  firestoreConnect([
    { collection: 'projects' }
  ]),
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
)(Header);
```